# Writing PHP to run a Python script on a webpage

Tags: php, html

I have a python bubble sorting script that I wish to run on a webpage using PHP. I took a PHP script that performed a similar action and tried to modify it to work for this purpose. My python script bubbleSort.py takes two variables, the sort size (Ns) and repetitions (R). The title of this script is lab42.php

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    session_start();
    require_once("config.php");
    $sSize = $_GET["sSize"];
    $sRep = $_GET["sRep"];
    print "Size($Size) Rep($Rep) \n";
    echo "<pre>";
    echo exec("python/bubbleSort.py ".$sSize." ".$sRep." ".SERVER." ".USER." ".PASSWORD." ".DATABASE." 2>&1", $output);
    var_dump ($output);
    echo "</pre>"; 
    /*
    $command= escapeshellcmd("python/bubbleSort.py ".$Size." ".$Rep." 2>&1");
    $output = shell_exec($command);
//  exec("python/bubbleSort.py ".$Size." ".$Rep." 2>&1", $output);
    echo $output;
    */
?>
```

However, when I try to run it on the webpage, it does not perform the bubble sort. Rather, it just reloads the page with the variables added on to the end of the address. Here is the part of the webpage source where I try to call the PHP script.

```
<h2 class="h2" >Lab4.2 Online</h2>
          <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
            <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    World of Sorts
            </div>
            <div class="card-body"> 
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <span class="btn btn-primary btn-small" data-toggle="collapse" href="#bubbleSort">
                            Magic of Bubble Sorting
                    </span>
                    <div id="bubbleSort" class="collapse">
                        <form class="form-signin">
                            <div class="row">
                                <input type="number" name="sSize" min="1000" max="9000" class="col form-control" placeholder="Sort size(N) [1000-9000]" required>
                                <input type="number" name="sRep" min="1" max="5" class="col form-control" placeholder="Repeting [1-5]" required>
                            </div>
                            <button id="lab42" class="btn btn-small btn-primary btn-block mt-2">
                                Run
                            </button>
                        </form>
                        <hr>
```

Comment: *when I try to run it on the webpage, it does not perform the bubble sort. Rather, it just reloads the page with the variables added on to the end of the address* - and what do you expect exactly?

Comment: It is supposed to run the bubble sorting algorithm and print the results on the web page

Comment: This `print "Size($Size) Rep($Rep) \n";` cause *page with the variables added on to the end of the address*

Comment: Try `echo "Size($Size) Rep($Rep) \n";`